# D7 Fullcalendar: drag/drop/resize returns 404 error

Tags: 7, javascript

when I drag/drop or resize an item, the js console returns:

*Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)*

localhost/drupal7/fullcalendar/ajax/update/resize/380

*Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)*

localhost/drupal7/fullcalendar/ajax/update/drop/380

Of course the changed items are not being saved.

Any ideas? Everything else is working fine. Im using the latest version of the fullcalendar library and the latest version of the fullcalendar module.